# How to Overwrite a Series Value through Conditional Expression?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I'm trying to overwrite a new column within a DataFrame based on a conditional expression:

1. `if df['service'] == 'PE1' or 'PE2':`
2. Change the existing value in df['service'] to equal the original df['service'] + df['load port'].
   `# if ['load port] == 'ABC' then new value == PE1ABC`
3. else: keep the original value in df['service'] `# in other words != 'PE1' or 'PE2'.`

I'm trying to use the .merge() to "VLOOKUP" from another DataFrame. However, the 'PE1' and 'PE2' services require the load port. All other services have a 1:1 assignment.

Comment: post a sample input/output ([mcve])

Answer (score 1):

You may define a function with your conditions, than use `apply` function to change your column.

Example data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'service':['PE1','PE2','bla','ble','PE2'],\
                   'load port':['ABC','TEST','BLA','BLA','BLE']})
```

Output:

```
  load port service
0       ABC     PE1
1      TEST     PE2
2       BLA     bla
3       BLA     ble
4       BLE     PE2
```

Change function:

```
def changeService(row):
    if row['service'] == 'PE1' or row['service'] == 'PE2':
        return row['service'] + row['load port']
    return row['service']
```

Apply change function so as to overwrite your column:

```
df['service'] = df.apply(changeService, axis = 1)
```

Output:

```
  load port  service
0       ABC   PE1ABC
1      TEST  PE2TEST
2       BLA      bla
3       BLA      ble
4       BLE   PE2BLE
```

**Note:** It is recommended your change function always have a `return`, otherwise some rows will be filled with `NaN` values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I actually had something similar but forgot the return row...

Answer (score 0):

you can use [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to perform the task such as:

```
import numpy as np
df['service'] = np.where((df['service'] =='PE1')|(df['service'] =='PE2'), #conditions
                          df['service']+df['load port'], #result if conditions are met
                          df['service']) # result if not
```

The method with `apply` from **@Lorran Sutter** is good but if your dataframe is big, this method will be faster.

Comment: This was amazing! Thank you so much! It's the equivalent to an '=IF' Statement in excel! :)